# I have problem in using 3 DIV tags in order to have 3 blocks in a row

Tags: html, css

I started learning HTML/CSS recently and I'm trying to design the first page of a site by using these 2! I want to have 3 parts including logo, search box and signup button (from right to left) in the header part but I have a problem in it. The signup part doesn't stay in a row which other parts are. What's the problem with my code?

Here's my code:

```css
body {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Header {
    height: 93px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.Logo {
    display: block;
    background: url('images/logo.png') no-repeat right center;
    height: 77px;
    width: 319px;
    float: right;
    margin: auto;
}

.Search {
    height: 93px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}
   
 .Search input[type=text] {
        border: none;
        direction: rtl;
        font-family: Tahoma;
        font-size: 16px;
        background: url('images/srch.png') no-repeat right center;
        padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
        margin: 25px 10px 0 0;
    }

.Sign_up input[type=button] {
    float: left;
    height: 93px;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #c00000;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url('images/sign_up.png') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
 <div class="Header">
            <a href="." class="Logo">
                &nbsp;
            </a>

            <div class="Search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
                &nbsp;
            </div>
           
           <div class="Sign_up">
               <input type="button" id="SignUpButton" onclick="SignUpPage()" value="sign up" />
           </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>

 </div>
```

Comment: logo will be aligned left side or right side?

Comment: It should be on the right side

Answer (score 2):

Remove **float: right** and replace **margin** into **margin-left** from class **.Logo**.

```css
body {
            background: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .Header {
            height: 93px;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }

        .Logo {
            display: block;
            background: url('images/logo.png') no-repeat right center;
            height: 77px;
            width: 319px;
            margin-left: auto;
            text-align: center;
            background: #d1e3e6;
        }

        .Search {
            height: 93px;
            width: 220px;
            float: left;
            border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
            border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
        }

        .Search input[type=text] {
            border: none;
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: url('images/srch.png') no-repeat right center;
            padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
            margin: 25px 10px 0 0;
        }

        .Sign_up input[type=button] {
            float: left;
            height: 93px;
            width: 100px;
            border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
            border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
            border-bottom: 8px solid #c00000;
            direction: rtl;
            font-family: Tahoma;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: url('images/sign_up.png') no-repeat right center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="Header">
        <a href="." class="Logo">
            All Set
        </a>

        <div class="Search">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
            &nbsp;
        </div>

        <div class="Sign_up">
            <input type="button" id="SignUpButton" onclick="SignUpPage()" value="sign up" />
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display: inline;
```

to each of their css

eg

```
.Search {
    display: inline;
    height: 93px;
    width: 220px;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}

 .Search input[type=text] {
      display: inline;
      border: none;
      direction: rtl;
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 16px;
      background: url('images/srch.png') no-repeat right center;
      padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
      margin: 25px 10px 0 0;
   }

   .Sign_up input[type=button] {
      display: inline;
      float: left;
      height: 93px;
      width: 100px;
      border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
      border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
      border-bottom: 8px solid #c00000;
      direction: rtl;
      font-family: Tahoma;
      font-size: 16px;
      background: url('images/sign_up.png') no-repeat right center;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="Header">
            <div>
<a href="." class="Logo">
                Logo Goes Here
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="Search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
                &nbsp;
            </div>

           <div class="Sign_up">
               <input type="button" id="SignUpButton" onclick="SignUpPage()" value="sign up" />
           </div>
 </div>
```

Css

.header{
    width: 100%;

```
div{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 33.3%;
   background: yellow;
}

div:nth-child(1), div:nth-child(3){
   background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header class is a flex container and then you use floats for the flex items in the container. So you are mixing these two concepts, but in my experience it is better to keep it with one of them. Anything you want to achieve, you can do with flex OR with floats.

As flex is the more modern (and simple) approach, I would stick with that one. Here is a very good article about aligning items in a flex container:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the floating property because when you're using flexbox method to align the column no need to use `float` to align the column.

For further assistance comment for more information.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

body {
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.Header {
    height: 93px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.Logo {
    display: block;
    background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/200') no-repeat right center;
    height: 93px;
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.Search {
    height: 93px;
    width: 220px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
}

.Search input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url('images/srch.png') no-repeat right center;
    padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;
    margin: 25px 10px 0 0;
}

.Sign_up input[type=button] {
    height: 93px;
    width: 100px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-left: 1px solid #d1d5dc;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #c00000;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url('images/sign_up.png') no-repeat right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header">
    <a href="#" class="Logo"></a>

    <div class="Search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
    </div>

    <div class="Sign_up">
        <input type="button" id="SignUpButton" onclick="SignUpPage()" value="sign up" />
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```